# OpenGL Compute Shader - correct memory barrier usage

Tags: opengl, gpu, shared-memory, memory-barriers, compute-shader

I'm hoping to be able to read and write to potentially the same elements of a SSBO as part of a fluid sim using compute shaders but I'm having trouble with syncing. I have a test shader that is run 16 times, with three options below that hopefully shows what I'm trying to do.

```
layout  (std430, binding=8) coherent buffer Debug
{
  int debug[ ];
};

shared int sharedInt;

layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

void main()
{
    ///////     1.     ///////
    sharedInt = debug[0];
    memoryBarrierShared();
    barrier();
    debug[0] = sharedInt[0] + 1;
    memoryBarrierShared();
    barrier();

    // Print debug[0]: 1


    ///////     2.     ///////
    atomicAdd(debug[0], 1);

    // Print debug[0]: 16


    ///////     3.     ///////
    sharedInt = debug[0];
    memoryBarrierShared();
    barrier();
    atomicExchange(debug[0], debug[0]+1);
    memoryBarrierShared();
    barrier();

    // Print debug[0]: 1
}
```

*Just to be clear I'm only running one of the options at a time.

The result I'm trying to get for all of them is for debug[0] to equal 16, though I need to use the something like the 1st or 3rd option in my simulation as I need to read and write to the SSBO in the same thread.

I'm not sure that I'm understanding the role of the shared variable, and as I understand memoryBarrierShared() should make the read and write of sharedInt visible to every thread in the work group, though if I make there is only one work group dispatched it is the same result.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, why there's a shared variable, or what your barriers are intended to accomplish. You say you want `debug[0]` to be 16, but it's really unclear why #2 is not an acceptable solution to that problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm not able to use #2 as I have to read from debug[0] and then later add 1 to it. 
In the simulation I have a ssbo that represents a 3D grid or cells that store which particles are currently each cell. For each cell I store the num of particles, and the indices of the particles in the cell. When filling the grid a compute shader is executed for each particle, which finds the cell it's in, then depending on the number of particles in the cell, is added to the appropriate memory slot, so I have to read the number of particles and then increment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the gist is that those additions in variant 1 and 3 are not part of the atomic operation. first you read from the shared variable/ssbo, then you perform the addition, then you write. if all invocations read the same value, they all have the same result from the addition and write the same value.

to make the addition part of the atomic operation, well, you use atomicAdd, just like you did in variant 2.

here's your code annotated with some explanations:

```
///////     1.     ///////

// all invocations read debug[0] into the shared variable (presumably 0)
sharedInt = debug[0];

// syncing. but since all wrote the same value into the SSBO, they all would read the same value from it,
// since values written in one invocation are always visible in the same invocation.
memoryBarrierShared();
barrier();

// all invocations do the addition and add 1 to that shared variable (but not write to the shared variable)
// then they all write the result of the addition (1) to the SSBO
debug[0] = sharedInt[0] + 1;

// another syncing that does not help if the shader ends here.
memoryBarrierShared();
barrier();

// since they all write 1, there is no other output possible than a 1 in the SSBO.
// Print debug[0]: 1


///////     2.     ///////
// all invocations tell the "atomic memory unit" (whatever that is exactly)
// to atomicly add 1 to the SSBO.
// that unit will now, sixteen times, read the value that is in the SSBO,
// add 1, and write it back. and because it is does so atomicly,
// these additions "just work" and don't use old values or the like,
// so you have a 16 in your SSBO.
atomicAdd(debug[0], 1);

// Print debug[0]: 16


///////     3.     ///////

// as above, but this has even less effect since you don't read from sharedInt :)
sharedInt = debug[0];
memoryBarrierShared();
barrier();

// all invocations read from debug[0], reading 0.
they all add 1 to the read value, so they now have 1 in their registers.
// now they tell the "atomic memory unit" to exchange whatever there is in
// debug[0] with a 1. so you write a 1 sixteen times into debug[0] and end up with a 1.
atomicExchange(debug[0], debug[0]+1);
memoryBarrierShared();
barrier();

// Print debug[0]: 1
```